# Absolute positioning within a div container with flexible height

Tags: html, css, position, height

Here is an **example** what I want to do with HTML and CSS:

[image]

**Explanation**
I am dependent to a plugin in WordPress which generates column for column. I want that the height of the overall table (at the moment a div-table) depends on the highest column (in my example column 2). Each column has a flexible div-container at the top and a div-container with a fixed height an the bottom (named sticky in the example above).

Any ideas how to realize that? I tried it in different ways but was not able to get want I want to have. This is the current code which I am using: http://jsfiddle.net/6Jg4y/

```
<div class="multiinline">
  <div class="multiinline-row">
    <div class="multiinline-cell">
     <div class="multiinline-cell-top">
       <div>Description 1</div>
     </div>
     <div class="multiinline-cell-bottom">
      <div>Sticky</div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="multiinline-row">
    <div class="multiinline-cell">
     <div class="multiinline-cell-top">
       <div>Description 2</div>
     </div>
     <div class="multiinline-cell-bottom">
      <div>Sticky</div>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="multiinline-row">
    <div class="multiinline-cell">
     <div class="multiinline-cell-top">
       <div>Description 3</div>
     </div>
     <div class="multiinline-cell-bottom">
      <div>Sticky</div>
     </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of, is if the parent most element (.multiinline) has a fixed height. Then you can set `.multiline-cell` to position:relative, and `.multiline-cell-bottom` to position:absolute and bottom:0.
Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/6Jg4y/1/

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer but in your example the .multiline-cell-bottom is now at the bottom of the page and not at the bottom of the .multiline-cell element. If I try to set a height for the .multiline-cell it doesn't change anything.

Comment: In the fiddle it's working fine for me. What browser are you using? Don't forget to add `position:relative` to the .multiline-cel.

Comment: It doesn't work in FF 28 but in Safari 7. That's not a good deal. Do you have any ideas how to solve this specific problem or how to solve this problem in another way?